Positive sequence with linear recursion relation involving positive convergent sequences as coefficients.
I wanted to try this exercise after solving this question: A sequence of nonnegative numbers defined by three convergent sequences, which is a duplicate of Convergence of a sequence defined by a linear recurrence with converging coefficients.
My problem is a generalization of the latter questions, this time I consider $k \in \mathbb{N}$ alongside with $k+2$ positive sequences
$$\left(u_n^0\right)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}, \, \left(u_n^1\right)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}, \dots \left(u_n^k\right)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \quad \text{and} \quad \left(v_n\right)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$$
which converge respectfully to $u_0,\dots ,u_k$ and $v$ with the one condition that $\exists i \neq j, \, u_i \neq u_j$ or we could lower this by just ensuring they are not all non-zero since conditions for convergence seems to be a bit more complicated (see at the end).
Now let $\left(x_n\right)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a positive sequence satisfying the following recursion condition for $n \in \mathbb{N}$:
$$u_n^k x_{n+k} + u_n^{k-1} x_{n+k-1} + \cdots +u_n^0 x_n = v_n.$$
How to prove (or disprove regarding specific cases) that $\left(x_n\right)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges?
I've done a small amount of work and there is some progress but the last part is harder than the original case.

First we can conclude with a similar reasoning that $\left(x_n\right)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded, and that if it converges, its limit is $x = \frac{v}{u_0 + \cdots +u_k}$.
Now we have by setting $y_n = x_n -x$
$$\begin{align*}
0&= \sum_{i=0}^k u_n^i x_{n+i} - v_n = \sum_{i=0}^k (u_n^i - u_i) x_{n+i} + \sum_{i=0}^k u_i x_{n+i} - (v_n-v) - v\\
&=  \sum_{i=0}^k u_i (x_{n+i}-x) +\sum_{i=0}^k u_i x+ \sum_{i=0}^k (u_n^i - u_i) x_{n+i} - (v_n-v) - v\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^k u_i y_{n+i} + \left(\sum_{i=0}^k (u_n^i - u_i) x_{n+i} - (v_n-v)\right) + \left(x\sum_{i=0}^k u_i - v\right)\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^k u_i y_{n+i} - \epsilon_n + 0
\end{align*}$$
With $\epsilon_n \to 0$.
Now what is somewhat useful is to have a simple recursion relation, not one of order $k$ we suppose wlog that $u_k \neq 0$. In order to pursue, we set $\gamma_i = \frac{u_i}{u_k}$ and
$$Y_n = \begin{pmatrix}
y_n \\ y_{n+1} \\ \vdots \\ y_{n+k-1}
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
U = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots &  0\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots  & \vdots\\
\vdots &  & \ddots & \ddots  & 0\\
0 & \cdots  & \cdots & 0 & 1 \\
-\gamma_0 & -\gamma_1 & \cdots & \cdots & -\gamma_{k-1}
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
E_n = \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ \vdots \\ 0\\ \epsilon_n
\end{pmatrix}$$
Now $U$ is cool matrix called Compagnon matrix and its minimal polynomial is
$$\Pi_U (T)= T^ k+ \gamma_{k-1}T^{k-1} + \cdots + \gamma_1 T + \gamma_0$$
and we have
$$Y_{n+1} = UY_n + E_n$$
and if we iterate it $r$ times, we get
$$Y_{n+r} = U^r Y_n + \sum_{i=1}^{r} U^{i-1} E_{n+r-i}$$
Now suppose the subordinate norm of $U$ verifies $\left\|U\right\| < 1$ we win since it is submultiplicative, but if it is not the case is seems pretty complicated.

Now for the rest I have observation but no concrete solution:

It seems to me that $\left\|U\right\| = 1$ is the worst case (generalization of $a=b$ in the original pb) so we need (and it is not sufficient) at least that $1$ and $-1$ are not roots of $\Pi_U$. I think we should just set that no element of the complex unit circle must be a root of $\Pi_U$.

I guess we could have a contradiction on the boundedness of $x_n$ if the component of $Y_n$ corresponding to a Jordan block associated with an eigenvalue $>1$ in module did not converge to $0$.
And then it would ensure that every component associated with eigenvalues $>1$ in module must converge and since the other are associated with eigenvalues $<1$ in module they would have to converge too. The problem is that the operator norm of a Jordan block $J(\lambda,m)$ is $|\lambda| + \frac{1}{2(n-1)}$ or something like that.


I'm thinking about this but I figured that I could ask the community for some advice, any help would be appreciated!.

Update
I may have managed to solve the problem but I made a small supposition in my answer concerning the operator norm of iterated powers of a Jordan Block.

I think I have it: We have $P \in \operatorname{GL}_k(\mathbb{C})$ and $J$ a Jordan block matrices with blocks $J(\lambda_1,m_1),\dots ,J(\lambda_q,m_q)$ such that
$$J = PUP^{-1}$$
We set $Z_n = PY_n$ and $D_n = PE_n$ and this gives us
$$Z_{n+1} = JZ_n + D_n$$
We can reduce by projecting onto every subspace associated to the $\lambda_i, m_i$: they are associated to the subspaces $V_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus V_r$ where $V_i = \{0\}^{m_1 + \cdots + m_{i-1}} \times \mathbb{C}^{m_i} \times \{0\}^{n-(m_1 + \cdots +m_i)}$ so let us suppose wlog that
$$Z_{n+1} = J(\lambda,m) Z_n + D_n$$
With $m >1$ otherwise it was already dealt in the original case. Indeed if we can prove that on each of these subspaces it converges, then we are good. I will denote $J_\lambda := J(\lambda,m)$, recall that $J_\lambda = \lambda I_m + N$ with $N$ the nilpotent matrix of order $k$ with the second diagonal full of ones and that
$$J_\lambda^s = \sum_{j=0}^s \binom{s}{j} \lambda^{j} N^{s-j}$$
We still have
$$Z_{n+r} = J_\lambda^r Z_n + \sum_{i=1}^{r} J_\lambda^{i-1} D_{n+r-i}$$
We have $\|J_\lambda^l\| = \Theta( \lambda^l)$ for $|\lambda | \neq 1$ but I am not sure (chatgpt gave me the result and my intuition tells me so).
And we also have
$$\mu(J_\lambda^l):= \min_{\|X\| = 1} \left\langle X,J_{\lambda}^l X \right\rangle = \Theta (\lambda^r)$$
If $\lambda = 0$ the convergence is pretty direct since $J = N$ so up to a certain rank
$$Z_{n+r} = \sum_{i=1}^{m} N^{i-1} D_{n+r-i} \to 0$$
We thus have two positive constants $A,B$ such that $A \lambda^r \leq \mu(J_\lambda^r)\leq \left\|J_\lambda^r \right\| \leq B \lambda^r$.
We set $d_n = \sup_{k\geq n} \|D_n\|$ (we use canonical norm for vectors and operator norm for matrices).

Case 1: $|\lambda| < 1$:
We have
$$\begin{align*}
\left\|Z_{n+r}\right\| &\leq \left\| J_\lambda^r \right\| \|Z_n \| + \sum_{i=1}^{r} \left\|J_\lambda^{i-1}\right\| \| D_{n+r-i}\|\\
&\leq B |\lambda|^r + \sum_{i=1}^{r} B |\lambda|^{i-1} d_n\\
&= B|\lambda|^k + \frac{B}{1-|\lambda|}d_n \to 0
\end{align*}$$
Case 2: $|\lambda| > 1$.
Let us suppose that $Z_n$ does not converge to $0$, then there exists $\eta>0$ such that for any $N$ there exists $n > N$ verifying $\|Z_{n}\| > \eta$.
Let $\epsilon = \frac{A}{B}\frac{|\lambda|-1}{2}\eta$ and consider some $N$ such that $d_N < \epsilon$. We choose some $n > N$ such that $\|Z_{n}\| > \eta$.
$$\begin{align*}
\left\|Z_{n+r}\right\| &\geq \left\| J_\lambda^r Z_n \right\| - \left\| \sum_{i=1}^{r} J_\lambda^{i-1}  D_{n+r-i}\right\|\\
&\geq \mu\left(J_\lambda^r\right) \|Z_n \| - \sum_{i=1}^{r} \left\|J_\lambda^{i-1} \right\| \| D_{n+r-i}\|\\
&\geq A |\lambda|^r \eta - \sum_{i=1}^{r} B|\lambda|^{i-1} d_n\\
&\geq A|\lambda|^r \eta - B\frac{|\lambda|^r}{|\lambda|-1}\epsilon\\
&= |\lambda|^r \left(A \eta - \frac{B}{|\lambda|-1}\epsilon \right)\\
&= |\lambda|^r \frac{A \eta}{2} \to \infty.
\end{align*}$$
Which is absurd since $Z_n$ is bounded, hence $Z_n \to 0$.


So as a result we get a sufficiently good necessary condition: if
$$u_k T^k + \cdots + u_1 T + u_0$$
Is non zero and all its complex roots have a modulus different than $1$ then $\left(x_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \to \frac{v}{u_0 + \dots + u_k}$.
