Convergence of infinite geometric series of matrix
Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and consider the series:
$$S = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} A^k$$
The task is to show that series converges when all eigenvalues of A are strictly smaller than 1.
My professor has suggested to use Jordan Canonical form to approach this problem.
However I am not sure how do I form a convergence criteria that will help in moving forward in the problem.
I have attempted to consider the partial sums:
$$S_{m+1} \equiv \sum_{k=0}^{m+1} A^k \;\;\;\text{ and }\;\;\; S_{m} \equiv \sum_{k=0}^{m} A^k$$
And then use these to form the product $S_{m}S_{m+1}^{-1}$ similar to how it is done in case of scalars, so to see whether:
$$||S_{m}S_{m+1}^{-1}|| < 1 \text{ strictly}$$
However, this has two problems that I could not resolve:

How do I ensure/know that $S_m$ is invertible?
My guess is that asking whether $S_m$ is invertible or not is like doing the circular reasoning of whether S is convergent or not; thus, is there any other alternative to comparing ratios?

What should be the correct approach to this problem?

Without Jordan this is hard since $|A| < 1$ is not equivalent to $\max |\lambda| < 1$ you don't need invertibility

Your advisor was correct. Try thinking about what happens when $A$ is diagonal and go from there.

Also, I don't understand why you would want to consider the quotient of partial sums.

And if you have trouble reasoning try considering low dimensions ($n=1,2...$)

If you want some insight, try mimicking my proof of this problem (it is in the answers part) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5000740/positive-sequence-with-linear-recursion-relation-involving-positive-convergent-s. All you need to do is to show that $|J_\lambda^k| = O(|\lambda|^k)$ for $|\lambda| <1$

Mimicking the proof for scalars would be to show that $S = (1-A)^{-1}$. That requires showing that $I-A$ is invertible (not too hard) and, because of the partial sum identity $(1-A)\sum_{k=0}^m A^k = 1-A^{m+1}$ (also not hard), showing that $A^n$ tends to the $0$ matrix as $n\to\infty$ (here Jordan forms should help).

@Klaus I was trying to do similar reasoning done for scalars series like if the partial sum is $S_m = \sum_k^m a_k$, then one could see $S_m$ as another sequence and utilise the fact that convergence of series would require $S_m/S_{m+1} < 1$ to be true.

@Aditya But that's wrong. $\frac{S_m}{S_{m+1}} < 1$ only implies that the sequence of partial sums is increasing. This is neither necessary nor sufficient for convergence. Of course, if it is also bounded, then you have a sufficient condition, but it's still not necessary as for example $A = -\frac{1}{2}$ shows. So I don't think this gets you anywhere even if it was true.
